# how does one manipulate Dictionaries in an Array in Swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

i am trying to programmatically manipulate an array of dictionaries in Swift 3.

```
var selectedQuestion: [String: String] = [:]

var trivia: [[String : String]] = [
  ["a": "1", "z": "10"],
  ["a": "2", "z": "9"],
  ["a": "3", "z": "8"],
  ["a": "4", "z": "7"]
]

trivia.removeAtIndex(triviaSource.trivia.indexOf(selectedQuestion))
```

the error from XCode says:
"cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of:[String, String])'

---

i am deliberately trying to keep this fairly basic in approach.

any thoughts on this?

am i barking up the wrong tree all together by trying to structure and manipulate my data this way?

Comment: The reason is that dictionaries are not `Equatable` ...

Comment: If the dictionaries in your array have static keys, you should use an array of `struct`s instead. You can then make that struct `Equatable` and use `index(of:)`.

Comment: Thanks everybody!